# Is it possible that a C++ program gives different results on different x86 hardware?

Tags: c++

i want to know if someone has experience with C++ programs which are built on a x86 system, and after releasing it for x86 systems (but for other processor hardware, f.e. AMD, Intel) some results differ. 
So the only thing that changed is the hardware.

The two things i have in mind are:

1. floating point standard IEEE (I don't know how strict the processor manufacturers comply with that)
   (Especially for iterative solvers, like FEM solvers, where one result is based on the result of the previous result. So small differences could lead to different results, f. e. 10000 iterations.)
2. Multi-threading

I heard such things now several times.
And I'm just interested if there are some proofed facts related to that topic.

Comment: 3). You are relying on some undefined behavior.

Comment: @Asha When you rely on *undefined* behavior, your program is invalid. However, you can write a valid program that relies on *unspecified* behavior, in which case it may be executed differently on different hardware.

Comment: What about reading the value of an environment variable like `PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER`? Practically you can't create an exhaustive list of things that *could* make a difference. You'd pretty much have to go through the entire C++ standard and for everything in there, check whether or not the compiler you built with pins down the behavior to be the same regardless of OS version and configuration (including driver versions) and hardware.

Answer (score 2):

There's always the [Pentium FDIV bug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentium_FDIV_bug) for starters, although some compilers can take this into account.

Some compilers can generate code to take advantage of SIMD instructions so could give different results between SIMD and non-SIMD versions when doinf floating point.

There are also some instructions that behave differently on different CPUs, pushf/popf for example.

So, yes, programs can behave differently on different hardware (it is, afterall, how programs that identify CPUs work).

Comment: Shift/rotate instructions give different results on different CPUs (Intel vs AMD and different Intel CPUs among themselves) when the shift count is large. There are some other common instructions that behave slightly differently.

Answer (score 0):

Not going to discuss you first (1) case, but pretty sure that exists a lot of commands (usually internal/undocumented) that behave in different way.

But concerning against multithreading (2) - I can tell that behavior of the same processor on the same process can produce different results.  In general multithreading (especially on hyper-thread and multicore processor) is random matter. It depends of lot factors- not only of manufacturer, but also on loading of process, kind of DMA controller... Even more there is special thread technique (random thread boost) - that invokes random generator to improve response of multithread engine.

Answer (score 0):

It's called a race condition.
( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition )